# How to select the control with the lowest tabindex?

Tags: winforms

Given a control that has child controls. How do you give focus to the child control that has the lowest tabindex without looping through all the controls?

Comment: I can't think of any other way to programatically determine the control with the lowest tabindex unless you store that information somewhere when the controls are created. Without a loop how else would you check everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution doesn't have the performance you are looking for, but it's the "easy way."  There may be an "easier way" that I am ignorant of.

```
var firstControl = this.AllChildControls().OrderBy(m => m.TabIndex).First();
firstControl.Focus();
```

The code snippet is dependant on the following extension method.

```
/// <summary>
/// Preforms a preorder iteration through all children of this control, recursively.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public static IEnumerable<Control> AllChildControls(this Control control)
{
   foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
   {
        yield return child;
        foreach (var grandchild in child.AllChildControls())
            yield return grandchild;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't need recursive searches in this case. This will work.
Dim xcon = (From item In Me.Controls.Cast(Of Control)() Where item.TabStop = True Order By item.TabIndex Select item).First

Answer (score 2):

I will do it by looping through the controls, there is nothing wrong with that. That is probably the simplest solution.